Usefulness of non-blocking mode on OpenSSL memory BIOs?
I'm a little lost on the usefulness of configuring an OpenSSL memory BIO (BIO_s_mem()) in non-blocking mode, I imagine that it has a use but I'm not sure I see it.
A memory BIO has the advantage of having no waits or limitations, right? I imagine it as a sort of dynamic allocator, but if it's more of a circular buffer with a limit, non-blocking mode would seem useful to me.
Apart from a complete filling of the BIO memory I do not see any other scenario where a call to SSL_write or SSL_read could block. I find very little documentation on this scenario.
I would like to be sure to make the right decision by limiting OpenSSL in blocking mode with the BIO memory in my application (which itself manages asynchronous I/O)
UPDATE: After exploring the OpenSSL source code a little I was able to understand that the memory BIOs are indeed dynamic buffers and do not seem to have any other limitation than those of the available RAM.
My question therefore remains: What is the benefit of OpenSSL non-blocking mode on a BIO memory?
Thanks

Why does there have to be?  BIOs are a general-purpose tool, and non-blocking modes are very useful for some BIOs such as socket-based ones.  Does the OpenSSL BIO_s_mem() code even implement a non-blocking mode?

@AndrewHenle This is the question I'm asking myself, the OpenSSL documentation is ambiguous on memory BIOs and the BIO_set_nbio function doc does not indicate a particular scenario for memory BIOs. Logically I imagine that memory BIOs are instantaneous and OpenSSL operations will be directly terminated on the first call whether blocking or non-blocking (unless there are internal OpenSSL mechanisms that need time, outside of IO operations) ? thanks
